# Localized resource variable in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I've the following problem.

I know we can create a resource in the gradle file like this:

resValue "string", "app_id", "hello_world"

But is there any possibility to localize this string in different languages from within the gradle file?

Comment: I am not sure that it is supported out of the box. Why do you need it? Why can't you achieve this by using native Android l10n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to do this just by creating different variables in gradle.properties and reference them in the strings.xml

Example:

Gradle.properties:

`APP_NAME="HelloWorld"
    APP_NAME_ES="HolaMundo"`

build.gradle

`resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', APP_NAME
resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME_ES', APP_NAME_ES`

strings.xml (english)

`<string name="app_name">@string/APP_NAME</string>`

strings_es.xml (english)

`<string name="app_name">@string/APP_NAME_ES</string>`

Comment: This is a bad solution. Gradle does not provide a l10n feature, but the Android framework does. So there is no way to apply your solution for a large number of languages, without repeating each of the three steps for each of them. Also, you did not show any reason to use Gradle for l10n resource values.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by default. Try to add your strings in localized folders or use flavors/dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle Android plugin does not support the addition of localized resources. You can check the [plugin documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html) and its reference on the [`ProductFlavor`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:resValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) class for more details and an overview of all methods.

However, you could edit your question to explain the scenario that would require such a feature. The `resValue` method is mainly used to add simple resources depending on the build, e.g. inserting the build number into the *About* section of the app.